# Components of State vector in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, notation, quantum-states

I am currently learning quantum mechanics and I am trying to understand the connection between the wave function and the state vector.
Is it correct to say that the components of the state vector of a quantum system are all possible wavefunctions in that state?

Comment: Could you clarify how (if at all) your sources define/describe what state vectors and wavefunctions are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A state vector is just a wavefunction where the domain doesn't need to be $\mathbb{R}^d$. Similarly, you can call wavefunctions vectors because the functions used in quantum mechanics (square integrable ones) are elements of a space which is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. *I.e.* a vector space.

A simple example is a large atom with a magnetic moment. In the Stern-Gerlach experiment, quantum fluctuations of its position are negligible but its spin (which can be up or down) is highly probabilistic. So instead of a wavefunction $\psi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{C}$, we just need $\psi: \{0,1\} \to \mathbb{C}$. A function from a two element set to $\mathbb{C}$ can be regarded as a two component vector so we can write this object as
\begin{align}
\left | \psi \right > = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $|a|^2$ is the spin-up probability and $|b|^2$ is the spin-down probability. This is also written
\begin{align}
\left < + | \psi \right > = a, \quad \left < - | \psi \right > = b.
\end{align}
Depending on how formal you want to be, the normalization condition $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ can also be seen as an integral of $|\psi|^2$ except using the counting measure instead of the Lebesgue measure.

We can also consider the opposite case. A particle with no spin but probabilistic position on a line. Position is a continuous degree of freedom so our $\psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ will be a vector with "a continuum of components". Instead of being able to project $\left | \psi \right >$ onto just two basis states ($\left < + \right |$ or $\left < - \right |$), we will be able to project it onto infinitely many position eigenstates. One for each position we can imagine the particle to have. The eigenstates can be labelled by $\left < x \right |$ and the projection by $\left < x | \psi \right >$ which is nothing more than $\psi(x)$ in the usual function notation.

Since we now have an all-encompassing framework that accounts for both continuous and discrete degrees of freedom, we can combine the two and consider things like $\psi: \mathbb{R} \times \{0, 1\} \to \mathbb{C}$ for particles with uncertain positions and spins. This allows us to consider projections like $\left < +, x | \psi \right >$ or $\left < -, y | \psi \right >$. In this situation, textbooks often use a hybrid notation where the $2 \times \infty$ components of the state vector are written as two functions worth of components. Something like
\begin{align}
\left | \psi \right > = \begin{pmatrix} \psi_+(x) \\ \psi_-(x) \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
This may have given rise to your notion of a vector consisting of many wavefunctions.

Comment: Great answer, but a small note: The notation in your last equation is a bit weird, since an $x$ appears on the RHS but not on the LHS. I guess this is a common abuse of notation, but, in my experience, also a common source of confusion when first encountering Dirac notation/ intro quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between wave functions and state vectors is the *exact* same relationship as between vector components and vectors in Euclidean vector space.

When you have an "ordinary" vector in 3D Euclidean space, given in terms of components, such as

$$\mathbf{v} = \langle 1, -2, 5 \rangle$$

you've likely seen them written with a subscript notation, e.g. $v_x = 1$, $v_y = -2$, and $v_z = 5$. You can think of this as a *function* from the label, here $x$, $y$, or $z$, to the corresponding component number, here $1$, $-2$, and $5$. The function, remember, is the association between the two, not how it's written.

In the case of quantum mechanics, though, the vectors can have infinitely many - even *continuously* many - "components". Thus, it becomes more natural to use function notation directly, and we call such a function a "wave function". In particular, $\psi(x)$ is the "$x$th component" of the vector $|\psi\rangle$ in some basis (usually the position basis given the use of $x$ as the variable [note this $x$ is not the same as the *label*-$x$ from before], but other bases are possible).